# Repeating Code vs. Multiple Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I have been cleaning up code that handles save data for Contacts and Clients. My goal has been to overhaul my code in order to maximize maintainability, since my project has undergone some severe code rot. In doing so, I have encountered a dilemma in inheritance structure.

`class SaveFile` is my base class for anything that gets saved onto the hard drive.

`class GeneralContact(SaveFile)` is a base class for any kind of contact.

`class PersonalContact(GeneralContact)` keeps track of data for personal contacts, while `class CorporateContact(GeneralContact)` keeps track of data for corporate contacts.

My difficulty lies in how to structure for clients. There are two types of clients: personal and corporate.

I could do `class PersonalClient(PersonalContact)` and `class CorporateClient(CorporateContact)`. However, both the personal and corporate clients would use essentially the same methods and attributes, so I would be repeating code.

I could also do `class GeneralClient`, and then `class PersonalClient(PersonalContact, GeneralClient)` and `class CorporateClient(CorporateContact, GeneralClient)`, which would only require me to implement the client code once, and then override the `__str__` methods for both.

So my question is, is there a preferable/more pythonic choice between using single inheritance and repeating code, or using multiple inheritance and digging into those complexities?

Comment: If most of your classes are reusing the same code, why not just have a general class for them? `class Contact` and add attributes `contract_type` to define General/Personal/Corporate? Same thing for `class Client` and attribute `client_type`? Am I missing something here?

Comment: They share some functionality, such as the ability to save to hard drive, or a place to save email addresses. However, the save structure for siblings is different enough that having one large class that covers multiple different contracts results in messy code that is difficult to maintain. This was one of the many, many culprits that contributed to code rot because I had to consider the many ways each modification would affect the multiple iterations of each class.

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is, is there a preferable/more pythonic choice between
> using single inheritance and repeating code, or using multiple
> inheritance and digging into those complexities?

The situation you described is what multiple inheritance was designed for.  There are two separate blocks of reusable code.  Multiple inheritance let's you use both.

Whether you encounter "complexities" or not depends on the situation:

- If there are no overlapping method names between the two parent classes, then multiple inheritance tends to be as simple as single inheritance.

  ```
  class A:
      def p(self):
          pass

  class B:
      def q(self):
          pass

  class C(A, B):
      'Both A.p() and B.q() are inherited'
  ```
- If there is an overlap, but only one method should run, it is also simple.  Just order the classes so that the one with the dominant overriding methods goes first.

  ```
  class A:
      def p(self):
          pass

  class B:
      def p(self):
          pass

  class C(A, B):
      'Only A.p() is used'
  ```
- If there is an overlap and both parent methods need to run, the simplest solution is to have the child method call both parent methods.

  ```
  class A:
      def p(self):
          pass
  class B:
      def p(self):
          pass

  class C(A, B):
      'Both A.p() and B.p() are called'

      def p(self):
          A.p(self)
          B.p(self)
  ```
- Really, the only complex cases are when you want to design cooperative classes that can be freely mixed and that are fully decoupled from one another. The techniques for achieving that goal are discussed in ["Python's super() considered super"](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).